# SSH Connection starts a bash process but wanted to start a process as soon as instance is launched on Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have created an AMI of my instance on AWS and had shared that with my teammate and he wanted to start the server with exact my configuration. I have also written a bash script which starts the tmux in the background and triggers the python script. But when my teammate launch the instance his server is accessible with configuration required. But the bash script doesn't runs unless he does one ssh to the newly build instance. Can I know what is wrong in this approach? Any suggestions and answers would be appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can define the bash script in Crontab before creating the AMI. Thus, it will create a new image and run the Crontab bash script when opened. You can add the following parameter to your crontab file.

```
nano /etc/crontab
```

The following line to the top line:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

At the bottom line you can add:

```
@reboot /dir/to/your-script.sh >> /home/user/logs/crontab.log 2> & 1
```

The following line to the top line:
PATH = / bin: / usr / local / bin

At the bottom line you can add:
@reboot /dir/to/your-script.sh >> /home/user/logs/crontab.log 2> & 1

The ">>" sign makes it send the result of crontab operations to the .log file in the relevant directory, not the system's default e-mail.